# Need help to deploy cloud code to Parse Platform

Tags: parse-server

Is PARSER-CLI still working on the Parser Platform?

It seems that there is no longer support to PARSE-CLI, so the cloud code can be no longer be deployed without changing the server code itself.

Is there another alternative?

Comment: back4App have an cli called `b4a` that essential does the same thing as the CLI

Comment: But it seems to me that b4a only works on back4App platform, not in a custom parse deployment, on Heroku for instance.

Comment: correct... but for a few dollars a month, it is (in my opinion) worth having a team of experts looking after your Parse Server ....